# How to do pending approval in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

In web-application there a lot of customers and they can interact between themselves. 
I have Action in my **Service.Business** layer like :

```
public void TransferMoneyViaBank(Customer c1, Customer c2, Bank b);
```

and i want to do following : when **c1 invoke method**, user authorized as a **bank_manager** should get notification (or just update table of pending requests) and allow or reject transfer. Only then c2 will recieve money from c1 or both get message of failure. 
I have an idea to use Signletone pattern and some static class(table in DB) where all pending actions records are stored (like a CPU Scheduling).

Is it good solution or there are already done methods\libraries to solve this task?

Comment: Just drop static classes and singleton pattern, keep data in DB tables for pending operations and yes, you're on the way